# Vagrant stopped working. Access denied

Tags: windows, vagrant

I have been using a vagrant setup with VirtualBox for two weeks now and it was working fine.  Yesterday I tried to use vagrant and found that none of the commands work.  They all result in an error with a callstack (in Ruby?).
I am using Windows 7 with VirtualBox 4.3.12 (because my corporate environment uses BeyondTrust and 4.3.12 was the only version I could get to work).

windows> vagrant status --debug

```
 ...
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SMB synced folders
 INFO global: Loading plugins!
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: vagrant-share
 INFO vagrant: `vagrant` invoked: ["reload", "--debug"]
DEBUG vagrant: Creating Vagrant environment
 INFO environment: Environment initialized (#<Vagrant::Environment:0x265c728>)
 INFO environment:   - cwd: C:/Users/Scott/hootenanny
 INFO environment: Home path: C:/Users/Scott/.vagrant.d
 INFO environment: Local data path: C:/Users/Scott/hootenanny/.vagrant
DEBUG environment: Creating: C:/Users/Scott/hootenanny/.vagrant
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_plugins_loaded
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: environment_plugins_loaded #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x385ff50>
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_load
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: environment_load #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x3731b38>
 INFO cli: CLI: [] "reload" []
DEBUG cli: Invoking command class: VagrantPlugins::CommandReload::Command []
DEBUG command: 'reload' each target VM...
DEBUG command: Getting target VMs for command. Arguments:
DEBUG command:  -- names: []
DEBUG command:  -- options: nil
DEBUG command: Loading all machines...
 INFO loader: Set :root = ["#<Pathname:C:/Users/Scott/hootenanny/Vagrantfile>"]
DEBUG loader: Populating proc cache for #<Pathname:C:/Users/Scott/hootenanny/Vagrantfile>
DEBUG loader: Load procs for pathname: C:/Users/Scott/hootenanny/Vagrantfile
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:home, :root]
DEBUG loader: Loading from: root (evaluating)
DEBUG provisioner: Provisioner defined:
DEBUG provisioner: Provisioner defined:
DEBUG provisioner: Provisioner defined:
DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning
DEBUG push: finalizing
 INFO loader: Set "23533380_machine_default" = []
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:home, :root, "23533380_machine_default"]
DEBUG loader: Loading from: root (cache)
DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning
DEBUG push: finalizing
DEBUG base: Windows, checking for VBoxManage on PATH first
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "--version"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_unload
 INFO host: Autodetecting host type for [#<Vagrant::Environment: C:/Users/Scott/hootenanny>]
DEBUG host: Trying: arch
DEBUG host: Trying: darwin
DEBUG host: Trying: freebsd
DEBUG host: Trying: gentoo
DEBUG host: Trying: redhat
DEBUG host: Trying: slackware
DEBUG host: Trying: suse
DEBUG host: Trying: bsd
DEBUG host: Trying: linux
DEBUG host: Trying: null
DEBUG host: Trying: windows
 INFO host: Detected: windows!
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: environment_unload #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x370c440>
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/childprocess-0.5.8/lib/childprocess/windows/handle.rb:12:in `open': Access is denied. (5) (ChildProcess::Error)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/childprocess-0.5.8/lib/childprocess/windows/process.rb:70:in `launch_process'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/childprocess-0.5.8/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:82:in `start'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:122:in `block in execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in safe_chdir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:25:in `chdir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:25:in `block in safe_chdir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:24:in `synchronize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:24:in `safe_chdir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:121:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:22:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:430:in `block in raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:429:in `raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:367:in `block in execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17:in `retryable'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:362:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/meta.rb:159:in `block in read_version'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17:in `retryable'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/meta.rb:158:in `read_version'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/meta.rb:46:in `block in initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/meta.rb:41:in `synchronize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/meta.rb:41:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/provider.rb:20:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/provider.rb:20:in `usable?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:381:in `block in default_provider'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:379:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:379:in `default_provider'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174:in `block in with_target_vms'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:210:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:210:in `block in with_target_vms'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:209:in `map'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:209:in `with_target_vms'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/commands/reload/command.rb:37:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:302:in `cli'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:174:in `<main>'
```

I have tried:
1) Reinstall vagrant
2) Reinstall VirtualBox
3) Checking permissions in c:/users/scott/.vagrant.d
4) Checking permissions in c:/users/scott/hootenanny/.vagrant

Of course any help is appreciated.

Scott

Comment: do you run your command prompt as admin or super user ?

Comment: I did not elevate the prompt because my user account is admin and I've never had to elevate the prompt in the past.

Comment: I just tried it using a cmd window run with "run as admin" and the result was the same.

Comment: Please post the contents of your `Vagrantfile` and any provisioning scripts.

Comment: Those files have worked for weeks and I didn't make them.  They came from here:  [hootenanny](https://github.com/ngageoint/hootenanny).  VagrantProvision.sh and Vagrantfile are at the root directory of the repo.

Comment: Try rebuilding the box in a new directory and see if you have the same issues. There seems to be an issue with permissions (which it seems you are aware) but it would be strange for this to just stop working one day for no reason, so try creating the box again in a new location and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You could try moving your Vagrant root install directory from C:\Hashicorp to a folder under your User directory ie. C:\Users\Scott\Hashicorp and see if that eliminates any of the issues you have with running. Occasionally IT gets overzealous and anything outside of the user directories get declared read only in case of viruses trying to take over the system.

You may want to see if there is an option to the installer to change the path, otherwise you will probably need to edit the registry entries and shortcuts to point to the new location, which also may require editing your path. If you have administrator access (I'd assume you do if you can uninstall updates) then you should be able to perform all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the latest Microsoft security updates for .NET and Windows and Vagrant started working again.  They were dated 3/24/2016 on my machine.  Then just as I was trying to learn more, the corporate machine I'm on reinstalled the updates.  There is nothing I can do about that.  My company uses Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise and I really shouldn't be uninstalling their security updates as I am an engineer, not a system admin.

I hope this information helps someone else who was staring at the same Ruby callstack and wondering what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have also solved the problem by running Git bash as admin and calling vagrant up through that elevated console.

Thanks to codecomp, who replied on the similiar issue at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/vagrant-up-failing-trying-to-add-to-hosts

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it turned out that I *did not* have VirtualBox installed. As soon as I installed virtualbox, this error disappeared and vagrant status worked as expected (I also am working on a machine which is encumbered by many enterprise security applications, which may be why vagrant did not give me a more helpful error message).

I know this doesn't help OP, but thought I'd share my experience for the next person that follows a google search to this page.